# How to pass data from different tables in database to view in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 tables: Movie and Schedule

Movie.cs

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }      

    public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }

}
```

Schedule.cs

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public int MovieID { get; set; }       
    public DateTime ShowDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShowTime { get; set; }

    public Movie Movie { get; set; }        
}
```

In the Schedule/Index, I want to show a list of MovieNames which have MovieID in Schedule.

ScheduleControler.cs

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CinemaContext db = new CinemaContext();

        var moviename = (from m in db.Movies
                        join s in db.Schedules on m.MovieID equals s.MovieID
                        orderby m.MovieName descending
                        select new {
                            MovieName=m.MovieName
                        }).ToList();

        return View(moviename);
    }
```

However, when I tried doing like below, it didnt work.

```
@using Booking_Ticket_Management_System.Model;
@model IEnumerable<Schedule>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Choose movies";
} 

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
<ul>
    @foreach(Schedule moviename in @Model)
    {
        <li>
            @moviename
        </li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moviename` is a `List` of anonymous objects (`new { MovieName = m.MovieName }`)... but the view is expecting a `IEnumerable<Schedule>`.

Change your query to select `Schedule`s that include `Movie`s...

```
using System.Data.Entity;
// ....
var schedules = db.Schedules.Include(s => s.Movie)
                    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Movie.MovieName)
                    .ToList();
return View(schedules);
```

View

```
@using Booking_Ticket_Management_System.Model;
@model IEnumerable<Schedule>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Choose movies";
} 

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
<ul>
    @foreach(Schedule schedule in @Model)
    {
        <li>
            @schedule.Movie.MovieName
        </li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

If all you need is a list of movie names, you can change your query to return a `List` of strings...

```
var moviename = (from m in db.Movies
                join s in db.Schedules on m.MovieID equals s.MovieID
                orderby m.MovieName descending
                select m.MovieName).ToList();
```

View

```
@using Booking_Ticket_Management_System.Model;
@model IEnumerable<string>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Choose movies";
} 

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
<ul>
    @foreach(string moviename in @Model)
    {
        <li>
            @moviename
        </li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When I tried your first suggestion, there was an error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" at the line s => s.Movie

Comment: Make sure you include `using System.Data.Entity;` up top... I'll update my answer to reflect that. You can also use `.Include("Movie")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your projecting an anonymous object with the property `MovieName` to the view, *not* an `IEnumerable<Schedule>`.  You need to reference that property in your view.

```
@foreach(moviename in @Model)
{
    <li>
        @moviename.MovieName
    </li>
}
```

Comment: However MovieName is not a property of Schedule, but Movie. Therefore, I cant do something like @moviename.MovieName

Comment: The code `select new { MovieName=m.MovieName }` created a new anonymous object, *not* a `Schedule`.